How to publish SHORTCODe with php manually?
WordPress has the option to use a plugin and publish something by writing SHORTCODE in a post or page, and then the plugin will publish something.
How can I add random numbers to PHP and make them published via PHP and not via the page/post section?
For example, if I add this shortcode to a page/post it will publish something.
[ivory-search id="1146" title="AJAX Search Form"] 
But how do I add in php so that I do not add this manually on every page?
This code publishes pages and I tried to add the above shortcode under the <div class="entry-content"> but it did not work
Tried to add this also but did not work too:
echo do_shortcode('[ivory-search id="1146" title="AJAX Search Form"]');

Somehow I cannot put PHP code with shortcode here, so here are code snippets : https://codefile.io/f/v4RyXKKedT
and this is photo of my code:
Photo of code

you can use this function in the template file : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

please echo shortcode like
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ivory-search id="1146" title="AJAX Search Form"]'); ?>



are you added php tags?

your welcome. please vote up if you liked my answer
